# Hibernate @ManyToMany inserts 0 on the owning side of an insert

Tags: java, hibernate

Having a bit of bother trying to figure out how to get my @ManyToMany mapping working in Hibernate in Dropwizard (using dropwizard-hibernate 6.2).  I've tried several of the online examples.  I'm trying to persist a twitter stream with user_mentions saved in a Targets table which is m2m with the Tweets table.  So far all my attempts have been with an existing Target and a new Tweet (and due to my business rules, that will always be the case).  I'll show code momentarily, but the consistent problem I'm having is that that the tweets_targets table winds up in all cases with the target_id set to the correct value, but the tweet_id set to 0.

Code is based on an article here: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-many-to-many-annotation-mapping-tutorial/

```
// Target class
@Entity
@Table(name="targets")
public class Target {
private long id;
 private List<Tweet> tweets = new ArrayList<Tweet>();   
@Id
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="targets",targetEntity=Tweet.class)
    public List<Tweet> getTweets() {
        return tweets;
    }
    public void setTweets(List<Tweet> tweets) {
        this.tweets = tweets;
    }
}

// Tweet class
@Entity
@Table(name="tweets")
public class Tweet {
    private long id;
private List<Target> targets = new ArrayList<Target>();
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "targets_tweets", joinColumns = { 
        @JoinColumn(name = "tweet_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "target_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) 
    })
    public List<Target> getTargets() {
        return this.targets;
    }

    public void setTargets(List<Target> targets) {
        this.targets = targets;
        for(Target t: targets){
            t.getTweets().add(this);
        }
    }
}
```

The actual saving of a new Tweet is done in the DAO class which inherits from AbstractDAO in DropWizard. Relevant code is:

```
public long create(Tweet tweet) {
    tweet.setTargets(getTargets(tweet));    
    return persist(tweet).getId();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private List<Target> getTargets(Tweet tweet) {
    String[] mentions = tweet.getUserMentions().split(",");

    return namedQuery(Target.FIND_BY_HANDLE)
            .setParameterList("handles", mentions).list();
}
```

My named query just returns a list of all my targets based on their twitter handle as reported by the streams API.

Comment: What is `message` in the `create(Tweet tweet)` method?

Comment: typo, should've been tweet. corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, hopefully this will help someone else.

The Id's in my DB are autoincrementing (I know, there's all kinds of debate on that, but it's what I have to work with), so once I added the annotation `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)` to the Tweet's Id property, everything started working.

Comment: In these cases one has to wonder: why does Hibernate not complain? I've seen more instances where things were just wrong yet Hibernate just keeps on chugging along. And I do mean as wrong as defining a oneToMany mapping that targets completely the wrong entity.

Comment: Agreed. I was also surprised that the DB didn't complain, b/c when I looked at the INSERT queries it was attempting to insert 0 as the Id, and most DB's I've worked with will vomit over an attempted insert on an db generated field.